# Why is a traditional RAMDisk faster than a GPU RAMDisk?

Tags: memory, ssd, performance, gpu, ramdisk

I tried out the GPURamDrive software by prsyahmi on GitHub and I created a 5 GB RAM Drive using my nVidia RTX 2060's GDDR6 RAM. I also later created a 4 GB RAM Drive using AMD's Radeon RamDisk software. Using CrystalDiskMark6, I ran benchmarks on both RAM Drives as well as my main Samsung 850 EVO SSD. The results surprised me, the GPU RamDisk did indeed have blazing fast sequential read/write speed but the Samsung SSD actually outperformed the GPU RamDisk in other tests by quite a bit too. And then compared to a traditional RamDisk using the system's DDR4 memory, it completely blew the GPU RamDisk out of the water.

Isn't GDDR6 and even the older GDDR5 memory used in GPU's supposed to be significantly faster than DDR4 RAM? And for that matter also significantly faster than flash memory? Is it a software issue? Or is there something about GDDR6 RAM than makes it inherently inferior to DRAM when used for RAM Disks?

These were the results of the benchmarks:

RTX 2060 GDDR6 RamDisk:

[image: RTX 2060]

DDR4 RamDisk:

[image: DDR4]

Samsung 850 EVO SSD:

[image: SSD]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GDDR6 is indeed faster than DDR4, and the layout of memory on the graphics card does actually result in an even higher memory bandwidth than a standard DIMM.

The problem is that between your CPU and GPU is a (relatively) slow PCIe link and just then negotiate with the GPU for memory access. The CPU memory is connected directly to the CPU, while the GPU memory is intended for high speed access to the GPU.

I acknowledge that the theoretical [bandwidth of an x16 PCIe](https://www.gamersnexus.net/guides/2488-pci-e-3-x8-vs-x16-performance-impact-on-gpus) link is of the order of 16GB/s, but that's a theoretical bandwidth and the GPU memory might be mapped into the PC general memory address space, but to actually write to it requires negotiation of at least two busses, one of which is being used already by the device which owns it (the GPU).

The GPU is using that memory to draw the screen, granted it may not be using a significant amount of bandwidth to draw your desktop, but it does mean some level of contention between your RAM disk and the onboard controller.

Then there are protocols involved. A protocol for the PCIe link, a protocol/API for asking the GPU to store something in memory, a protocol/driver on top of that to present a disk interface to the operating system (which probably uses CPU memory to do all the overheads and calculations and GPU memory to store the actual data).

You are also most likely reading from that GPU ramdisk into a CPU memory buffer. Yes the data is immediately discarded but it needs to go *somewhere*. Yet another link in the chain.

There is also the problem that the particular driver you are using is working via a *programming interface* and that every time you attempt to read or write to a memory address in the RAM disk it has to be caught by the CPU, passed to the driver, converted to a memory location on the GPU by the driver, then the data transferred to or from the GPU. This would inherently involve a CPU based "memory copy" to go from the read location and be supplied to the driver. Everything in this stage, except for the final "put/gimme this bit of data" is entirely CPU constrained. The actual data transfer might be quite quick, but this is another overhead.

The GPU memory bandwidth *should* completely trounce your CPU memory bandwidth, but there are several more layers to access that memory. It is most efficient when doing bulk data handling *internally* rather than being used by a second source.

You are not "just" using the GPU as a ramdisk. There is a lot of CPU involvement in managing every step of the way and you are just using the GPU memory as a backing store via a lot of layers of interfaces.

Indeed from https://github.com/prsyahmi/GpuRamDrive

> **Using GPU RAM isn't as fast as host main memory**, however it is still faster than a regular HDD. ... This merely just a PoC (proof of concept), user who search for this kind of solution is advised to upgrade the RAM or buy a faster storage.

Comment: I'm not familiar with low-level GPU APIs, but I suppose they may not allow for direct memory access and the software in question is using some kind of hack to achieve it. This would mean that protocol overhead is even larger and could be the bottleneck here. Don't quote me on this though.

Comment: @gronostaj the driver uses either CUDA or OpenCL, so there is definitely some extra software and protocol overheads to allocate memory, negotiate to write and so on. I'm only familiar with them from an overarching perspective as well, but it makes sense that because it is not memory directly "owned" by the CPU that there is some working around to be done. Every write would have to be captured and redirected at least, meaning that CPU memory would be limiting the speed first, then big overheads eat into what's left of the bandwidth.

Comment: Another piece of information from [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/prsyahmi/GpuRamDrive/issues/5): _"There is also some bottleneck between ImDisk and its Proxy feature. When using ImDisk alone the seq read speed is around 4000-5000MB/s while using proxy feature (still using ram) the speed barely reach ~2000MB/s. This probably due to synchronized read/write and slow IPC mechanisms. Even if the PCIe bandwidth somehow increased, there is still bottleneck on ImDisk and little I can do about that."_

Comment: @gronostaj there is definitely more going on than simple "use this as ramdisk" and due to the way the system and GPU is structured I don't see any other way it can work. Write requests will always need a "from" buffer or data in CPU memory, and it will then be copied to the driver which is an immediate halving in effective CPU bandwidth. Then you have to transfer it across the bus to the GPU and so on. The CPU memory becomes a limiting factor.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I'm surprised that overhead with the CPU and ImDisk interface would cause such a significant bottleneck to the point where a typical SATA3 SSD can be faster than the GPU RAM Drive. I originally thought that something about GDDR6 made it inherently unsuitable for certain read/write operations like the 4K benchmarks but this definitely makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those things that looks like an awesome possibility when you first look at it, then you see that it's hidden away behind a couple of locked doors and there's a special handshake you have to do with the security guard at each door and you have to photocopy your drivers licence (using their slow copier) at the front entrance as well. What should be a 5 second flying visit becomes an hour to get through security just to *look* at something. GDDR *is* blazing fast. Modern graphics cards mention bandwidth of 256GB/s and up, it's just not easy to leverage from the outside.